# Cannot find module (with own model)

Tags: node.js, express, npm

This is probably an ultra-duplicated question, but i am really new with `node` (and `express` particularly) and any of those related questions could solve my problem:

Having this project structure:

```
├── app
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── user.js
├── package.json
├── server.js
```

I run the server and i am having this exception

```
jscherman@jscherman:~/Work/express-webservice-demo$ node server.js
Server started on port 8080

Error: Cannot find module './app/models/user'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jscherman/Work/express-webservice-demo/server.js:38:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
```

I am linking the model as follows:

```
var user = require('./app/models/user');
```

I am using these versions:

```
jscherman@jscherman:~/Work/express-webservice-demo$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:        15.10
Codename:       wily
jscherman@jscherman:~/Work/express-webservice-demo$ node --version
v5.5.0
```

I don't understand what is going on . I had understood that ./ means "starting from server.js path" but it's not working. Any help?

---

### EDIT

The following code

```
console.log('__dirname:', __dirname, '\nprocess.cwd():', process.cwd())
```

outputs:

```
__dirname: /home/jscherman/Work/express-webservice-demo 
process.cwd(): /home/jscherman/Work/express-webservice-demo
```

and `server.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var router = express.Router();

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('This is a simple middleware');
    next();
})


router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'Welcome to the api' });   
});

app.use('/api', router);


app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server started running on port 3000!');
});


var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/prueba', function(){
    console.log('Database connected successfully')
})

var User = require('./app/models/user');
```

finally, `user.js` (inside models folder)

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema   = new Schema({
    username: String,
    surname: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

Inspecting cache:

```
// with console.log(require.cache), output:
{ '/home/jscherman/Work/express-webservice-demo/server.js': 
   Module {
     id: '.',
     exports: {},
     parent: null,
     filename: '/home/jscherman/Work/express-webservice-demo/server.js',
     loaded: false,
     children: [],
     paths: 
      [ '/home/jscherman/Work/express-webservice-demo/node_modules',
        '/home/jscherman/Work/node_modules',
        '/home/jscherman/node_modules',
        '/home/node_modules',
        '/node_modules' ] } }
```

Comment: So, you have file path resolving issue.
Put all code from server.js here, or you can also verify cwd by `process.cwd()`

Comment: It sounds like your require path is correct, using `./` makes it relative to the currently executing module/file, so there's something else we're missing. I agree with @loadaverage that you should provide more code/context, particularly in server.js. What does the following output? `console.log('__dirname:', __dirname, '\nprocess.cwd():', process.cwd())` You could also try something like `var userPath = require('path').resolve(__dirname, 'app', 'models', 'user'); var user = require(userPath)` for troubleshooting.

Comment: Did your user.js has any exports?

Comment: @loadaverage I added some code. Could you take a look?

Comment: @superEb Check out my edit. Regarding the other require thing, it is still giving me the same error but with the entire path ('/home/jscherman/Work/express-webservice-demo/app/models/user')

Comment: @NileshMali Yes it does, i updated with `user.js` code, take a look.

Comment: Hmm, very strange. Your require() is correct and should works fine, also the are no difference about user.js file contents. The error is in file resolving. What node version and OS/Distro are you using?

Comment: Try to inspect require contents with console.log(require.cache); BTW: remove for a while all modules but user.

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question, but have you tried moving where the `require('./app/models/user')` statement gets executed in your server.js file (like move it to the top)?

Comment: @loadaverage Node v5.5.0, Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: @superEb Yes, it is in `server.js` file, and i have already tried moving it to the top but still the same :(

Comment: @loadaverage I tried removing all modules but user but still happening. Regarding require contents, i added the output at the bottom of the post. Shouldn't it be there the project path? in my case '/home/jscherman/Work/express-webservice-demo/'

Comment: Paths is correct. Really dunno what to say, very strange issue. If this helps, here is my output from 5.6.0 https://jsfiddle.net/ftw4c4y4/

Comment: @loadaverage thanks anyways!

Comment: No problemo :) Try to run your code in official Node.js Docker image (https://hub.docker.com/_/node/). I'm sure you have some buggy build or environment stuff. Run: cd ~/Work/express-webservice-demo && docker run -v `pwd`:`pwd` -ti node /bin/bash